# Fonts / Resolution are coming as stretched

Tags: 12.04, display, resolution, fonts

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 from the past one year and i like the system. Suddenly now the system settings somehow changed and all the fonts in all places of system [in desktop, in browser, in text editor] are coming as stretched and feels very uncomfortable. I don't clearly know the reason for this problem and one suspect is i installed Wine program to run safari browser but after that i removed it completely through some commands got from online...

My question : is it possible to revert back these settings to original settings. And also is it some fonts problem or some resolution problem? I tried resetting fonts using MyUnity / Unsetting tools but it doesn't help. Also tried resetting gnome desktop properties using some commands from online but it doesn't help. Or i need to reinstall Ubuntu itself ? Please help me, thanks...

I am not able to post image as i don't have 10 reputation, otherwise i could have posted it to get very clear understanding of problem

Comment: Is it only fonts or are images stretched as well?

Comment: @StenSoft everything, fonts and images coming as stretch...

Comment: one more thing is my screen is not cut off, it is coming as full but in stretched mode [like horizontal flattening]

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_c-YMyLcZG3YU1QdnIweEt5ZEk/view?usp=sharing) this is the google drive link to see the image of my computer which has problem. see  the screen is stretched...

Answer (score 0):

Your computer uses resolution with different aspect ratio than what is native for your monitor. Go to **System Settings → Display** and pick a different one.

Comment: thanks for your replay. but that thing i already tried , i selected different resolution options available and it doesn't help...

Comment: Are there black borders above and below? If so, the monitor is set to convert to 16:9.

Comment: xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768       60.1*+   40.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: no there is no black borders above and below... and i set the resolution as 1366 * 768 (16:9) ...

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_c-YMyLcZG3YU1QdnIweEt5ZEk/view?usp=sharing) this is the google drive link to see the image of my computer which has problem. see  the screen is stretched...@StenSoft

Comment: I don't see it stretched (the circles in Ask Ubuntu logo are circles and all icons are square as they should be) so it is a resolution problem. Which quite puzzles me if everything is stretched to sides (wider and smaller) and there are no black borders because there is no common larger aspect ratio wider than 16:9.

Comment: it may not be so stretched, but see the fonts and all it is stretched horizontally (it is wider and smaller) compared to my normal screen i had before... do you know any process (commands) to reset all the display related properties to default one ? or do you think this problem will solve if i re install ubuntu ?

Comment: The font in the title is exactly the same as on my screen and the icons are perfect squares (not stretched at all). Note that since your screen is stretched, you will see this image stretched as well :-) [You can use `unity-tweak-tool` to reset it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration).